# How do I use RegExp Replace to replace sentence?

Tags: regex, replace

How do I use RegExp Replace to replace below word?

--

(1) Replace/Remove what ever word start with "a" and end with "c"!

`Example (1): abc, xyz, axc, bbb, ccc ayc, a1c, abcc, axxyzc...`

`Replace after (1): , xyz, , bbb, ccc , , , ...`

--

(2) Replace/Remove what ever word start with "abc=" and end with "&"!

`Example (2): abc=123&xyz=111&abc=xgggf&abc=ffff&abc=xxxx&xyz=kkk&abc=zzz&`

`Replace after (2): xyz=111&xyz=kkk&`

--

Thanks~~~

Comment: on the no.2, are you parsing query strings?

Comment: Is your no.2 correct? You want to replace anything NOT starting with xyz= . Am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1):

```
var replaced = string.replace(/a.*?c/gi, "");
```

(2):

```
var replaced = string.replace(/(.*?)xyz=&(.*?)/gi, "$1,$2");
```

The above is using Javascript. But the general regex's will be the same in all regex flavors.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... but to replace "englishchinese" to "eXe", is that 

var replaced = string.replace(/e.*?e/gi, "X");